# setState value used in componentDidMount is not reflected in Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

**Component.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import request from 'superagent'

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {cats: []}
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        request('/api', (err, res) => {
            if (err) return;
            this.setState({
                cats: res.body.results
            })
        })
    },

    render() {
        let cats = this.state.cats
        let catsList = (
            <ul>
                {cats.map((c) => <li key={c.id}>cat</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
        return (
            <div>
                {cats.length ? catsList : null}
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

**Component.test.js**

```
jest.unmock('../app.js')
jest.unmock('superagent')

import React from 'react'
import {mount} from 'enzyme'
import nock from 'nock'
import App from '../app.js'

describe('App', () => {
    let ajaxFn
    beforeEach(() => {
        ajaxFn = nock('http://localhost')
            .get('/api')
            .reply(200, {
                results: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
            })
    })

    it('renders correct number of cats', () => {
        let wrapper = mount(<App />)
        expect(wrapper.state('cats').length).toBe(3)
    })
})
```

The test does not pass. `wrapper.state('cats').length` is always `0`.

I understand that `setState` doesn't guarantee to update state immediately,
however if I log 'cats' in the component, I can see it updating.

Answer (score 10):

If you end up setting state in your component in some context that enzyme doesn't know about, you will have to manually call `.update()` on the wrapper in order for it to get the updated version of the render tree.

```
it('renders correct number of cats', () => {
    let wrapper = mount(<App />)
    expect(wrapper.update().state('cats').length).toBe(3)
})
```

Comment: This worked for me, I wondered however why it doesn't update as a result of setState, does the wrapper traverse a copy of the render tree or something?

Comment: Leland, don't you need to ensure first that state update has happend before doing wrapper.update() ?

Comment: or we rely on the fact that the nock-ed ajaxFn is sync

Comment: I posted an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308214/react-enzyme-test-componentdidmount-async-call/40875174#40875174 .. it maybe similar to the Simon Hardman answer

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it was necessary to return a promise from the `it` callback and check the expectation in the `then` method of the promise.

In your case (assuming ajaxFn was a promise, or you could turn it into one) I think this would be approximately:

```
it('renders correct number of cats', () => {
    let wrapper = mount(<App />) 
    return ajaxFn.then(() => {
        expect(wrapper.state('cats').length).toBe(3);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with all the libraries you are using, but since your code is being executed asynchronously the test is finishing before the state can be updated. I was able to solve this problem by adding async/await to the test:

```
it('renders correct number of cats', async () => {
    let wrapper = await mount(<App />)
    expect(wrapper.state('cats').length).toBe(3)
})
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I didn't know `mount` was an async function!