# React Enzyme - Test `componentDidMount` Async Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

everyone.

I'm having weird issues with testing a state update after an async call happening in `componentDidMount`.

Here's my component code:

```
'use strict';


import React from 'react';
import UserComponent from './userComponent';
const request = require('request');


class UsersListComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      usersList: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    request('https://api.github.com/users', (err, res) => {
      if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
        this.setState({
          usersList: res.slice(0)
        });
      }
      else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.usersList.length) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="users-list">
        { this._constructUsersList() }
      </div>
    );
  }

  _constructUsersList() {
    return this.state.usersList.map((user, index) => {
      return (
        <UserComponent
              key={ index }
              name={ user.name }
              age={ user.age } />
      );
    });
  }
};


export default UsersListComponent;
```

Now, what I'm doing in my test files (I have a setup comprised of Mocha + Chai + Sinon, all working):

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import UsersListComponent from '../src/usersListComponent';


describe('Test suite for UsersListComponent', () => {
  it('Correctly updates the state after AJAX call in `componentDidMount` was made', () => {
    const server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    server.respondWith('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users', [
      200,
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': 2
      },
      '[{ "name": "Reign", "age": 26 }]'
    ]);
    let wrapper = mount(<UsersListComponent />);
    server.respond();
    server.restore();
    expect(wrapper.update().state().usersList).to.be.instanceof(Array);
    console.log(wrapper.update().state().usersList.length);
  });
});
```

State does not get updated, even though I call `update()` on wrapper. Length is still 0. Am I missing something here? Do I need to mock the server response in another way?

Thnx for the help!

Answer (score 13):

You can abstract the user list retrieval away from the react component via passing a function that returns a Promise so that instead of

```
  componentDidMount() {
    request('https://api.github.com/users', (err, res) => {
      if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
        this.setState({
          usersList: res.slice(0)
        });
      }
      else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

Replace it with

```
  componentDidMount() {
     var comp = this;
     this.props.getUsers()
        .then(function(usersList) {
          comp.setState({
            usersList: usersList
          });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
  }
```

And inside your test mock that `getUsers` function:

```
    it('Correctly updates the state after AJAX call in `componentDidMount` was made', (done) => {

      let resolveGetUsers;

      let getUsers = function() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                  resolveGetUsers = resolve;
                });
      }

      let wrapper = mount(<UsersListComponent getUsers={getUsers} />);

      resolveGetUsers([{ "name": "Reign", "age": 26 }]);


      // promise resolve happens in a subsequent event loop turn so move assertions inside setImmediate
      setImmediate(() => {

        expect(wrapper.update().state().usersList).to.be.instanceof(Array);
        ...

        done();
      });
    }
```

Note that I have done this and it works for me (even without the wrapper.update() part) and here I tried to apply it to your code example without running it..

Also note that it should work in cases other then componentDidMount too - like having an async action triggered after clicking a button for example..

Comment: Note that if this is used in `beforeEach()`, the `setImmediate()` section will probably cause errors, since the execution of its contents is deferred. Your tests will probably begin executing prior to completion of the `setImmediate()` block. To get around this, wrap the `setImmediate()` block in a `new Promise()` that's only resolved when all statements in the block are finished. Make the `beforeEach()` function async and have a line in there sth like: `await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* setImmediateBlock goes here; don't forget to put resolve() at the end of it. */ });`

Answer (score 2):

Give you my solution:

- enzyme 3.9.0
- enzyme-adapter-react-16 1.9.1
- react 16.8.0
- jest

**1- Mock data service**

You must mock the data service (usually something like axios or an other HTTP library).

File: `__mocks__/LogDataService.js`:

```
let searchData = {}

const LogDataService = {
    search: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        process.nextTick(() => resolve(searchData))
    ),
    setSearchData: (data) => searchData = data
}

export default LogDataService
```

**2- Tests**

File: `__tests__/toto.test.js`:

```
jest.mock('services/LogDataService')

import LogDataService from 'services/LogDataService';

// Declare a super promise that will synchro all promises
function flushPromises() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
}

it('renders without data', async () => {
    // Set dummy data
    LogDataService.setSearchData([])
    // The component we want to test that use
    // LogDataService.search method we just mock up
    const component = mount(<JobsExecutionTimeline />);
    // wait
    await flushPromises();
    // re-build the render
    component.update()
    // Compare to snapshot
    expect(toJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Excellent and you can shorten it to `await new Promise(setImmediate)` and drop the helper function if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/request and figured out that the 'body' parameter is missing from the callback.

It should look like

```
...
request('https://api.github.com/users', (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
      this.setState({
        usersList: body.slice(0)
      });
    }
...
```

Comment: Indeed it does. I definitely had an issue with that, but it didn't solve the real problem. So I worked it out eventually. Turns out I had to check setState in a timeout due to its async nature. Final implementation here - https://github.com/r31gN/tdd-react-enzyme/blob/master/tests/tests.full.js (I also switched to `superagent`, just personal preference).

Comment: Also used `nock` to mock the server response. Had weird issues with the fake server in sinon. Request was not getting caught. I might have to dig deeper into that (maybe I was doing some funky stuff there).