# How to TEST async calls made in componentDidMount that set the state of React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

What is the best way to **test that an async call within `componentDidMount` sets the state for a React component?** For context, the libraries I'm using for testing are `Mocha`, `Chai`, `Enzyme`, and `Sinon`.

Here's an example code:

```
/* 
 * assume a record looks like this:
 * { id: number, name: string, utility: number }
 */

// asyncComponent.js
class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            records: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // assume that I'm using a library like `superagent` to make ajax calls that returns Promises

        request.get('/some/url/that/returns/my/data').then((data) => {
            this.setState({
                records: data.records
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="async_component">
                { this._renderList() }
            </div>
        );
    }

    _renderList() {
        return this.state.records.map((record) => {
            return (
                <div className="record">
                    <p>{ record.name }</p>
                    <p>{ record.utility }</p>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }
}


// asyncComponentTests.js
describe("Async Component Tests", () => {
    it("should render correctly after setState in componentDidMount executes", () => {
        // I'm thinking of using a library like `nock` to mock the http request

       nock("http://some.url.com")
           .get("/some/url/that/returns/my/data")
           .reply(200, {
               data: [
                   { id: 1, name: "willson", utility: 88 },
                   { id: 2, name: "jeffrey", utility: 102 }
               ]
           });

       const wrapper = mount(<AsyncComponent />);

       // NOW WHAT? This is where I'm stuck.
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just assert that your state updated correctly?  I'm not all that familiar with using Enzyme and not using the `shallow()` api, but with shallow-rendered components you can assume that the state update is synchronous.

Comment: My question is more focused on the async part of this - if I were to assert the state initially after render, `records` would be the empty array. Instead, I'm hoping to make the assertion after the promise in `componentDidMount` sets the state to a non-empty array.

Comment: In reality, it is best practice to move that functionality out of the component so it can be tested separately and you can mock it for testing the component. But you could always use setTimeout. You have control over nock so you can be pretty sure about how long the response will take.

Comment: Just so I understand, when you're using nock, you can control how long it takes before the response comes back? And assuming thats the case, then you can make an assertion within the setTimeout after that amount of time has elapsed?

Comment: You *can* and it should work, but the suggestion to use a Flux architecture (i.e. redux) is also a good one. Your component's will be "dumb" in the sense that they just render what you give them, making testing easier (and synchronous).

Comment: Got it - that makes sense. Although unfortunately, our codebase doesn't currently make use of any Flux architecture but I'd still like to add some tests to any new components I add.

Comment: Note that moving state inherent to the component (and also not intended to be shared with other components) to a redux store seems like a not very good idea. I have posted an answer to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308214/react-enzyme-test-componentdidmount-async-call/40875174#40875174

Answer (score 3):

So, what you are really trying to test is that based on some mock data it *"should render correctly ..."*.

As some people pointed out, a good way to achieve that is by placing the data fetching logic into a separate container and have a "dumb" presentation component that only knows how to render `props`.

Here is how to do that:
(I had to modify it a bit for Typescript with Tslint, but you'll get the idea)

```
export interface Props {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    records: Array<any>;
}

// "dumb" Component that converts props into presentation 
class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="async_component">
                {this._renderList()}
            </div>
        );
    }

    _renderList() {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
        return this.props.records.map((record: any) => {
            return (
                <div className="record" key={record.name}>
                    <p>{record.name}</p>
                    <p>{record.utility}</p>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }
}

// Container class with the async data loading
class MyAsyncContainer extends React.Component<{}, Props> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            records: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        fetch('/some/url/that/returns/my/data')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({
                records: data.records
            });
        });
    }

    // render the "dumb" component and set its props
    render() {
        return (<MyComponent records={this.state.records}/>);
    }
}
```

Now you can test `MyComponent` rendering by giving your mock data as props.

Answer (score -1):

Ignoring the, sane, advice to think again about the structure, one way to go about this could be:

- Mock the request (fx with sinon), to make it return a promise for some records
- use Enzyme's `mount` function
- Assert that the state to not have your records yet
- Have your rest function use `done` callback
- Wait a bit (fx with `setImmediate`), this will make sure your promise is resolved
- Assert on the mounted component again, this time checking that the state was set
- Call your done callback to notify that the test has completed

So, in short:

```
// asyncComponentTests.js
describe("Async Component Tests", () => {
    it("should render correctly after setState in componentDidMount executes", (done) => {
        nock("http://some.url.com")
           .get("/some/url/that/returns/my/data")
           .reply(200, {
               data: [
                   { id: 1, name: "willson", utility: 88 },
                   { id: 2, name: "jeffrey", utility: 102 }
               ]
           });

        const wrapper = mount(<AsyncComponent />);

        // make sure state isn't there yet
        expect(wrapper.state).to.deep.equal({});

        // wait one tick for the promise to resolve
        setImmediate(() => {
            expect(wrapper.state).do.deep.equal({ .. the expected state });
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Note:

I have no clue about nock, so here I assume your code is correct

Answer (score -1):

IMO, this is actually a common issue which appears more complicated because of promises and `componentDidMount`:
You're trying to test a functions which are only defined within the scope of another function. i.e. You should split your functions out and test them individually.

**Component**

```
class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            records: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        request.get('/some/url/that/returns/my/data')
            .then(this._populateState);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="async_component">
                { this._renderList() }
            </div>
        );
    }

    _populateState(data) {
        this.setState({
            records: data.records
        });
    }

    _renderList() {
        return this.state.records.map((record) => {
            return (
                <div className="record">
                    <p>{ record.name }</p>
                    <p>{ record.utility }</p>
                </div>
            );
        });
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
// asyncComponentTests.js
describe("Async Component Tests", () => {
    describe("componentDidMount()", () => {
        it("should GET the user data on componentDidMount", () => {
            const data = {
                records: [
                    { id: 1, name: "willson", utility: 88 },
                    { id: 2, name: "jeffrey", utility: 102 }
                ]
            };
            const requestStub = sinon.stub(request, 'get').resolves(data);
            sinon.spy(AsyncComponent.prototype, "_populateState");
            mount(<AsyncComponent />);

            assert(requestStub.calledOnce);
            assert(AsyncComponent.prototype._populateState.calledWith(data));
        });
    });

    describe("_populateState()", () => {
        it("should populate the state with user data returned from the GET", () => {
            const data = [
                { id: 1, name: "willson", utility: 88 },
                { id: 2, name: "jeffrey", utility: 102 }
            ];

            const wrapper = shallow(<AsyncComponent />);
            wrapper._populateState(data);

            expect(wrapper.state).to.deep.equal(data);
        });
    });
});
```

**Note**: I've written the unit tests from documentation alone, so the use of `shallow`, `mount`, `assert`, and `expect` might not be best practices.