# Jest: tests can't fail within setImmediate or process.nextTick callback

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jasmine, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test for a React component that needs to complete an asynchronous action in its `componentWillMount` method. `componentWillMount` calls a function, passed as a prop, which returns a promise, and I mock this function in my test.

This works fine, but if a test fails in a call to `setImmediate` or `process.nextTick`, the exception isn't handled by Jest and it exits prematurely. Below, you can see I even try to catch this exception, to no avail.

How can I use something like `setImmediate` or `nextTick` with Jest? The accepted answer to this question is what I'm trying to implement unsuccessfully: [React Enzyme - Test `componentDidMount` Async Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308214/react-enzyme-test-componentdidmount-async-call).

```
it('should render with container class after getting payload', (done) => {
  let resolveGetPayload;
  let getPayload = function() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolveGetPayload = resolve;
    });
  }
  const enzymeWrapper = mount(<MyComponent getPayload={getPayload} />);

  resolveGetPayload({
    fullname: 'Alex Paterson'
  });

  try {
    // setImmediate(() => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      expect(enzymeWrapper.hasClass('container')).not.toBe(true); // Should and does fail
      done();
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // Never makes it here
    done(e);
  }
});
```

Jest v18.1.0

Node v6.9.1

Comment: have you read the docs about testing async stuff (http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#content)?

Comment: Yep, I'm not testing an asynchronous function, I'm testing a component that needs to wait for a promise.

Comment: But you create a promise, and even you resolve it in the test it will have no effect in the test run, you need at least return the promise from the test.

Comment: But you create a promise, and even you resolve it in the test it will have no effect in the test run, you need at least return the promise from the test.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue @AlexPaterson? I faced to same problem and the only thing that seems to work is to wrap the expect into try catch...comes out a bit ugly for my taste. Also this might be related; https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2059

Comment: Same stupid issue :((

Answer (score 11):

Another potentially cleaner solution, using async/await and leveraging the ability of jest/mocha to detect a returned promise:

```
// async test utility function
function currentEventLoopEnd() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
}

it('should render with container class after getting payload', async () => {
  
  // mock the API call in a controllable way,
  // starts out unresolved
  let resolveGetPayload; // <- call this to resolve the API call
  let getPayload = function() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      resolveGetPayload = resolve;
    });
  }
  
  // instanciate the component under state with the mock
  const enzymeWrapper = mount(<MyComponent getPayload={getPayload} />);
  expect(enzymeWrapper.hasClass('container')).not.toBe(true);

  resolveGetPayload({
    fullname: 'Alex Paterson'
  });

  await currentEventLoopEnd(); // <-- clean and clear !

  expect(enzymeWrapper.hasClass('container')).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Overcome that issue in the next way atm (also it solves the issue with Enzyme and async call in componentDidMount and async setState):

```
it('should render proper number of messages based on itemsPerPortion', (done) => {
  const component = shallow(<PublishedMessages itemsPerPortion={2} messagesStore={mockMessagesStore()} />);

  setImmediate(() => { // <-- that solves async setState in componentDidMount
    component.update();

    try { // <-- that solves Jest crash
      expect(component.find('.item').length).toBe(2);
    } catch (e) {
      return fail(e);
    }

    done();
  });
});
```

(Enzyme 3.2.0, Jest 21.1.6)

**UPDATE**

Just figured out another, better (but still strange) solution on that using async/await (and it still solving async componentDidMount and async setState):

```
it('should render proper number of messages based on itemsPerPortion', async () => {
  // Magic below is in "await", looks as that allows componentDidMount and async setState to complete
  const component = await shallow(<PublishedMessages itemsPerPortion={2} messagesStore={mockMessagesStore()} />);

  component.update(); // still needed
  expect(component.find('.item').length).toBe(2);
});
```

Also other async-related actions should be prefixed with `await` as well like

```
await component.find('.spec-more-btn').simulate('click');
```

Comment: I went with the updated code using `await wrapper.update()` as well. I noticed some tests required the `await` for the update and some didn't, even though I was testing the same component for similar things.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the callback block passed to `process.nextTick` or `setImmediate` in a `try`/`catch` works, as others have shown, but this is verbose and distracting.

A cleaner approach is to flush promises using the brief line `await new Promise(setImmediate);` inside an `async` test callback. Here's a working example of using this to let an HTTP request in a `useEffect` (equally useful for `componentDidMount`) resolve and trigger a re-render before running assertions:

#### Component (`LatestGist.js`):

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

export default () => {
  const [gists, setGists] = useState([]);

  const getGists = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://api.github.com/gists");
    setGists(res.data);
  };    
  useEffect(() => {
    getGists();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {gists.length
        ? <div data-test="test-latest-gist">
            the latest gist was made on {gists[0].created_at} 
            by {gists[0].owner.login}
          </div>
        : <div>loading...</div>}
    </>
  );
};
```

#### Test (`LatestGist.test.js`):

```
import React from "react";
import {act} from "react-dom/test-utils";
import Enzyme, {mount} from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
import mockAxios from "axios";
import LatestGist from "../src/components/LatestGist";

jest.mock("axios");

describe("LatestGist", () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.resetAllMocks());
  
  it("should load the latest gist", async () => {
    mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => 
      Promise.resolve({ 
        data: [
          {
            owner: {login: "test name"},
            created_at: "some date"
          }
        ],
        status: 200
      })
    );

    const wrapper = mount(<LatestGist />);
    let gist = wrapper
      .find('[data-test="test-latest-gist"]')
      .hostNodes()
    ;
    expect(gist.exists()).toBe(false);

    await act(() => new Promise(setImmediate));
    wrapper.update();

    expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    gist = wrapper
      .find('[data-test="test-latest-gist"]')
      .hostNodes()
    ;
    expect(gist.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(gist.text()).toContain("test name");
    expect(gist.text()).toContain("some date");
  });
});
```

Forcing a failed assertion with a line like `expect(gist.text()).toContain("foobar");` doesn't cause the suite to crash:

```
● LatestGist › should load the latest gist

expect(string).toContain(value)

  Expected string:
    "the latest gist was made on some date by test name"
  To contain value:
    "foobar"

    at Object.it (src/LatestGist.test.js:30:25)
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.12.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "24.7.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some things to note;

- `process.nextTick` *is* async, so the try/catch won't be able to capture that.
- `Promise` will also resolve/reject async even if the code you run in the Promise is sync.

Give this a try

```
it('should render with container class after getting payload', (done) => {
    const getPayload = Promise.resolve({
        fullname: 'Alex Paterson'
    });
    const enzymeWrapper = mount(<MyComponent getPayload={getPayload} />);

    process.nextTick(() => {
        try {
            expect(enzymeWrapper.hasClass('container')).not.toBe(true);
        } catch (e) {
            return done(e);
        }
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return fail(e)` instead of `return done(e);`?

Comment: there is no `fail` method to my knowledge, only the `done` callback: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#callbacks

Comment: It should be `done.fail(e)`. If you do `done(e)` the test will pass as `done()` doesn't take arguments. The `fail` function is documented on the Jasmine page here: [done.fail function](https://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction#section-54)

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Vladimir's answer + edit, here's an alternative that worked for me. Rather than `await` the mount, `await` the `wrapper.update()`:

```
it('...', async () => {

  let initialValue;
  let mountedValue;

  const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />);
  initialValue = wrapper.state().value;

  await wrapper.update(); // componentDidMount containing async function fires
  mountedValue = wrapper.state().value;

  expect(mountedValue).not.toBe(initialValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*-- Posting as an answer for one cannot format code blocks in comments. --*

Building upon Vladimir's answer, note that using async/await works in a beforeEach as well:

```
var wrapper

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Let's say Foobar's componentDidMount triggers async API call(s)
  // resolved in a single Promise (use Promise.all for multiple calls).
  wrapper = await shallow(<Foobar />)
})

it('does something', () => {
  // no need to use an async test anymore!
  expect(wrapper.state().asynchronouslyLoadedData).toEqual(…)
})
```