# Testing asynchronous componentDidMount that changes state with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

All I am doing in my code is upon `componentDidMount` being run, I am making an axios get request to GitHub, and setting some data back onto state. However, when I run the test it still says the state is an empty array.

Here is my component below:

```
export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            goodbye: false,
            data: []
        }

    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.func()
    }

    func = async () => {
        let data = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/gists')
        this.setState({data: data.data})
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    goodbye = () => {
        this.setState((state, currentProps) => ({...state, goodbye: !state.goodbye}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <h1>
                    Hello World
                </h1>
                <button id="test-button" onClick={this.goodbye}>Say Goodbye</button>
                {
                    !this.state.goodbye ? null :
                    <h1 className="goodbye">GOODBYE WORLD</h1>
                }
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

and here is my test:

```
it('there is data being returned', async () => { 
    const component =  await mount(<HelloWorld />)       

    component.update()

    expect(component.state('data')).toHaveLength(30)

})
```

I am very new to using Jest and am not sure what I am doing wrong. This app was built solely for testing out Jest with Enzyme. How can I test this component correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Testing a component that runs an async function from `componentDidMount` (or `useEffect` -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59604256/6243352)) must await a re-render before running assertions. [`wrapper.update`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) is used to sync Enzyme's component tree before running assertions but doesn't wait for promises or force a re-render.

One approach is to use [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_args), which runs its callback at the end of the event loop, allowing promises to resolve non-invasively.

Here's a minimal example for your component:

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, {mount} from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
import mockAxios from "axios";
import HelloWorld from "./HelloWorld";

jest.mock("axios");

describe("HelloWorld", () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.resetAllMocks());
  
  it("should call `axios.get` and set the response to `state.data`", async () => {
    const mockData = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
    mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({data: mockData}));

    const wrapper = mount(<HelloWorld />);
    await new Promise(setImmediate);
    wrapper.update();

    expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(wrapper.instance().state.data).toEqual(mockData);
  });
});
```

While this works, `wrapper.instance().state.data` is too tied to the internal state of the application. I'd prefer to write a test that asserts on the behavior, not the implementation; variable name changes should not force tests to be re-written.

Here's an example component where the updated data is rendered in the DOM and tested in a more black-box manner:

#### Component (`StackUsers.js`):

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

export default class StackUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {users: null};
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
  }
  
  async getUsers() { 
    const ids = this.props.ids.join(";");
    const url = `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/${ids}?site=stackoverflow`;
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    this.setState({users: res.data.items});
  }
  
  render() {
    const {users} = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {users
          ? <ul data-test="test-stack-users-list">{users.map((e, i) => 
              <li key={i}>{e.display_name}</li>
            )}</ul>
          : <div>loading...</div>
        }
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Test (`StackUsers.test.js`):

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, {mount} from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
import mockAxios from "axios";
import StackUsers from "../src/components/StackUsers";

jest.mock("axios");

describe("StackUsers", () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.resetAllMocks());

  it("should load users", async () => {
    mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({
      data: {
        items: [
          {"display_name": "Jeff Atwood"},
          {"display_name": "Joel Spolsky"},
        ]
      },
      status: 200
    }));

    const wrapper = mount(<StackUsers ids={[1, 4]} />);
    let users = wrapper
      .find('[data-test="test-stack-users-list"]')
      .hostNodes()
    ;
    expect(users.exists()).toBe(false);

    await new Promise(setImmediate);
    wrapper.update();

    expect(mockAxios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    users = wrapper
      .find('[data-test="test-stack-users-list"]')
      .hostNodes()
    ;
    expect(users.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(users.children()).toHaveLength(2);
    expect(users.children().at(0).text()).toEqual("Jeff Atwood");
    expect(users.children().at(1).text()).toEqual("Joel Spolsky");
  });
});
```

Now, the only things the test knows is that `axios.get` is used and the results should appear in an element with a specific `data-test` attribute. This does not unduly interfere with CSS classes, HTML structure or component internals.

For reference, here are my dependencies:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.12.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "24.7.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to mock await axios.get('https://api.github.com/gists') somehow.

Them probably you'll need to do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/lotif/c2dc0ead6ad9003ed3fc9ebe94a11e07) after component.update() to "wait".

Comment: why do I have to mock the axios.get() if all i'm looking for is to check to see if the state changes?

Comment: @mlisonek and what are you expecting in the state? Why do you think data should 
 toHaveLength(30)? Why not 50. I don't see it in your test.

Comment: I can see the data coming back from the front end and its an array of 30 objects containing information about gists

Comment: @mlisonek, do you mean that it is a real data from? From the web?