# How to Test a Reactcomponent which has Axios call in componentDidMount using JEST with ENZYME?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, jest-mock-axios

**Introduction**
I want to test a component that has axios call in componentDidMount. I have tried all the ways but ever time I'm facing the same issue with axios.

**Error:**

```
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
         |         ^
    at Welcome.loadUsers (src/Testing/welcome.js:23:9)
          at Welcome.componentDidMount (src/Testing/welcome.js:19:14)
          at fn (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:429:22)
          at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:781:16)
          at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:428:26)
          at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
          at Object.<anonymous> (tests/welcome.test.js:11:15)
```

**Techonlogy Stack - Package.json:**

```
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
```

**Welcome.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {loadUsers} from './api';

class Welcome extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            user: null,
            error: false,
            errMsg: ''
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            isLoading: true
        });
        this.loadUsers();
    }
    
    loadUsers=()=>{
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(resp=>{
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                user: resp.data,
                error: false,
                errMsg: ''
            });
        })
        .catch(exep =>{
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                user: null,
                error: true,
                errMsg: exep.message
            });
        });
    }
    
    render() {
        const {isLoading, user, error, errMsg} = this.state;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h2 className='helloWorld'>Hello World</h2>
                {
                    isLoading ? <h3 className='loader'>Loading...</h3> :
                    user != null ? <h2>Welcome {user.title}</h2> :
                    error ? <h3>{errMsg}</h3> : <h4>No Data Found</h4>
                }
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Welcome;
```

**Welcome.Tests.js** - 1st TestCase Simple Rendering is also not working facing the same error as stated above.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Welcome from '../src/Testing/welcome';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

jest.mock('axios');
let wrapper;

beforeEach(()=>{
    wrapper = shallow(<Welcome/>);
});

describe('<Welcome/>:: Rendering', ()=>{
it('should load hello world', ()=>{
except(wrapper.find(‘h2.helloworld’).text()).toEquals(‘Hello World’)
});

describe('<Welcome/>:: Mocking', ()=>{
    it('should fetch users', ()=>{
        const user = {
            userId: 1,
            id: 1,
            title: "test",
            completed: false
        };
        axios.get.mockResolvedValue(user);
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        return instance.loadUsers().then(data=> expect(data).toBe(user));
    });
});

describe('<Welcome/>:: Trigger Life Cycle',()=>{
    it('should check for componentDidMount',()=>{
        shallow(<Welcome/>).debug();
        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        jest.spyOn(instance, 'loadUsers'); 
        instance.componentDidMount();
        expect(instance.loadUsers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

Summary:

Test are Working fine **without axios** and it test cases. And If I place axios call, all testcase which are not even related to axios *(simple shallow rendering)* are also failed.

Comment: I'm not super crazy about dipping into an implementation detail like `.loadUsers`. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59604256/6243352) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59596718/6243352) may help. Offhand, I think you need to `mount` rather than `shallow`.

Comment: @ggorlen I have followed the steps as specified in 1 & 2 but still I'm facing the same error as specified on the top. Error is caused at the actual component <Welcome/> if I run the test case. And the same component <Welcome/> is working fine in the browser . Test cases are getting failed
 axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `axios-mock-adapter` a try:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';

describe('<Welcome/>:: Mocking', ()=>{
    it('should fetch users', ()=>{
        const user = {
            userId: 1,
            id: 1,
            title: "test",
            completed: false
        };

        const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        mock.onGet().reply(200, user);

        const instance = wrapper.instance();
        return instance.loadUsers().then(data=> expect(data).toBe(user));
    });
});
```