# How to write test cases for axios API call using Jest and Enzyme in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to writing test cases for react. What am I doing wrong in the below code?

My component

```
// Dummy.js

import React, {Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Dummy extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    error: false,
    data : []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  getData = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            name : response.data.data[0].first_name,
            data : response.data.data
        });

        return "Success"
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          error: true,
        });
      });
  };
  render() {
    return <div>
        <h1 data-testid ="test">{this.state.name}</h1>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

My test case

```
// dummy.test.js


import React from "react";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import Dummy from "../Dummy";
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("axios");

const data = {
  page: 2,
  per_page: 6,
  total: 12,
  total_pages: 2,
  data: [
    {
      id: 7,
      email: "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
      first_name: "Michael",
      last_name: "Lawson",
      avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      email: "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
      first_name: "Lindsay",
      last_name: "Ferguson",
      avatar: "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg",
    },
  ],
};

test("should fetch users", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Dummy />);
  const resp = {data: data};

  axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);

  wrapper
    .instance()
    .getData()
    .then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
      expect(wrapper.state("data")).toEqual(resp);
    });
});
```

Below is the error I am getting when trying to execute my test case.

```
FAIL  src/Dummy/__tests__/dummy.test.js
  × should fetch users (5 ms)

  ● should fetch users

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

      12 |   }
      13 |   getData = () => {
    > 14 |     axios
         |     ^
      15 |       .get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      16 |       .then((response) => {
      17 |         this.setState({

      at Dummy.getData (src/Dummy/Dummy.js:14:5)
      at Dummy.componentDidMount (src/Dummy/Dummy.js:11:10)
      at fn (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:429:22)
      at Object.batchedUpdates (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:807:16)
      at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/src/ShallowWrapper.js:428:26)
      at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/src/shallow.js:10:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Dummy/__tests__/dummy.test.js:32:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.862 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Don't know much about jest and enzyme. Please suggest functions/code which helps me on solving my problem.

Comment: I removed the offsite resource request -- see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also, [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Check out [Testing asynchronous componentDidMount that changes state with Jest and Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54465734/testing-asynchronous-componentdidmount-that-changes-state-with-jest-and-enzyme/59596718#59596718). I don't recommend testing implementation details like this -- `.getData()` is not a function the test suite should know about.

Answer (score 1):

When you directly mock any module or library, it's exports are replaced with undefined values. To be able to correctly mock `axios` and make it useful in your test-case, take a look at this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter

Also, depends on the `enzyme` version, in newest versions `shallow` is triggering `componentDidMount` lifecycle, so you need to mock the HTTP client before shallow-rendering - https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html

Answer (score 0):

`mockResolvedValue` is a Jest function that should be called like so:

```js
axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockedUsers);
```

The rest of the test should be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow below steps:**

1. Create the `mockaxios.js`

```
export default {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }))
};
```

2. Inside your `dummy.test.js` mock it with jest

```
import axios from 'axios'
import mockAxios from './mockaxios.js'
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    __esModule: true, 
    default: mockAxios 
}));
```

3. And finally use it as

```
mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(resp));
```

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined ``` is the error I am getting.