# Trigger useEffect in Jest and Enzyme testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Jest and Enzyme to test a React functional component.

MyComponent:

```
export const getGroups = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(groupApiUrl);
    return await data.json()
};

export default function MyWidget({
  groupId,
}) {
  // Store group object in state
  const [group, setGroup] = useState(null);

  // Retrive groups on load
  useEffect(() => {
    if (groupId && group === null) {
      const runEffect = async () => {
        const  { groups  } = await getGroups();
        const groupData = groups.find(
          g => g.name === groupId || g.id === Number(groupId)
        );

        setGroup(groupData);
      };
      runEffect();
    }
  }, [group, groupId]);

  const params =
    group && `&id=${group.id}&name=${group.name}`;
  const src = `https://mylink.com?${params ? params : ''}`;

  return (
    <iframe src={src}></iframe>
  );
}
```

When I write this test:

```
  it('handles groupId and api call ', () => {
    // the effect will get called
    // the effect will call getGroups
    // the iframe will contain group parameters for the given groupId


   act(()=> {
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyWidget surface={`${USAGE_SURFACES.metrics}`} groupId={1} />) 
        console.log(wrapper.find("iframe").prop('src'))
    })
   })
```

The returned src doesn't contain the group information in the url. How do I trigger useEffect and and everything inside that?

EDIT: One thing I learned is the `shallow` will not trigger `useEffect`. I'm still not getting the correct src but I've switched to `mount` instead of `shallow`

Answer (score 15):

Here's a minimal, complete example of mocking `fetch`. Your component pretty much boils down to the generic fire-fetch-and-set-state-with-response-data idiom:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

export default function Users() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      setUsers(await res.json());
    })();
  }, []);

  return <p>there are {users.length} users</p>;
};
```

Feel free to run this component in the browser:

```html
<script type="text/babel" defer>
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Users = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      setUsers(await res.json());
    })();
  }, []);

  return <p>there are {users.length} users</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Users />, document.querySelector("#app"));
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can see the component initially renders a value of 0, then when the request arrives, all 10 user objects are in state and a second render is triggered showing the updated text.

Let's write a naive (but incorrect) unit test, [mocking `fetch`](https://www.leighhalliday.com/mock-fetch-jest):

```
import {act} from "react-dom/test-utils";
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, {mount} from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import Users from "../src/Users";

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe("Users", () => {
  let wrapper;
  let users;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockResponseData = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
    users = mockResponseData.map(e => ({...e}));
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    global.fetch = jest.fn(async () => ({
      json: async () => mockResponseData
    }));
    wrapper = mount(<Users />);
  });
  
  it("renders a count of users", () => {
    const p = wrapper.find("p");
    expect(p.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(p.text()).toEqual("there are 3 users");
  });
});
```

All seems well--we load up the wrapper, find the paragraph and check the text. But running it gives:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: "there are 3 users"
Received: "there are 0 users"
```

Clearly, the promise isn't being awaited and the wrapper is not registering the change. The assertions run synchronously on the call stack as the promise waits in the task queue. By the time the promise resolves with the data, the suite has ended.

We want to get the test block to `await` the next tick, that is, wait for the call stack and pending promises to resolve before running. Node provides [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.dev/learn/understanding-setimmediate) or [`process.nextTick`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) for achieving this.

Finally, the [`wrapper.update()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html) function enables synchronization with the React component tree so we can see the updated DOM.

Here's the final working test:

```
import {act} from "react-dom/test-utils";
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, {mount} from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

import Users from "../src/Users";

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe("Users", () => {
  let wrapper;
  let users;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    const mockResponseData = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
    users = mockResponseData.map(e => ({...e}));
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    global.fetch = jest.fn(async () => ({
      json: async () => mockResponseData
    }));
    wrapper = mount(<Users />);
  });
  
  it("renders a count of users", async () => {
    //                           ^^^^^
    await act(() => new Promise(setImmediate)); // <--
    wrapper.update();                           // <--
    const p = wrapper.find("p");
    expect(p.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(p.text()).toEqual("there are 3 users");
  });
});
```

The `new Promise(setImmediate)` technique also helps us assert on state before the promise resolves. `act` (from `react-dom/test-utils`) is necessary to avoid `Warning: An update to Users inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)` that pops up with `useEffect`.

Adding this test to the above code also passes:

```
it("renders a count of 0 users initially", () => {
  return act(() => {
    const p = wrapper.find("p");
    expect(p.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(p.text()).toEqual("there are 0 users");
    return new Promise(setImmediate);
  });
});
```

The test callback is asynchronous when using `setImmediate`, so returning a promise is necessary to ensure Jest waits for it correctly.

This post uses Node 12, Jest 26.1.0, Enzyme 3.11.0 and React 16.13.1.

Answer (score 5):

With jest you can always mock. So what you need is:

1. In your unit test mock useEffect from React

```
jest.mock('React', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('React'),
  useEffect: jest.fn(),
}));
```

That allows to mock only useEffect and keep other implementation actual.

2. Import useEffect to use it in the test

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
```

3. And finally in your test call the mock after the component is rendered

```
useEffect.mock.calls[0](); // <<-- That will call implementation of your useEffect
```

Comment: at first i thought this is a feasible approach, but this only works if you test separate component with lets say one or two `useEffect` calls. the more are involved, the harder this approach gets. i've got here anyway only because we had some async functionality inside useEffect -  and that basically brakes tests; or it needs some explicit synchronisation mechanism to be testable.

Comment: With this, I get the error 
Property 'mock' does not exist on type '(effect: EffectCallback, deps?: DependencyList | undefined) => void'.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect has already been triggered and working, the point is that its an `async` operation. So you need to wait for the fetch to be completed. one of the ways that you can do that is:
1. write your assertion(s)
2. specify the number of assertion(s) in your test, so that jest knows that it has to wait for the operation to be completed.

```
 it('handles groupId and api call ', () => {
    // the effect will get called
    // the effect will call getGroups
    // the iframe will contain group parameters for the given groupId
    expect.assertions(1)
    const wrapper = shallow(<UsageWidget surface={`${USAGE_SURFACES.metrics}`} groupId={2} />)
    wrapper.update()
    expect(whatever your expectation is)
  });
```

since in this example i just wrote on assertion,

```
expect.assertions(1)
```

if you write more, you need to change the number.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't help. How can I tell if my useEffect is calling the function? I assume logs placed in the component wont render out in the the jest cli

Comment: are you sure this is the right test? your component name is `MyWidget` but you are testing `UsageWidget`

Comment: Sorry, that's just a spelling mistake

Comment: I dont think you need `act` function here. go back to the original format with `shallow` from enzyme. write your test and assertion and and number of assertions. It should work fine.

Comment: It runs but the results do not match what's expected. I read that Node doesn't have fetch built-in. Could the issue be related to node trying to run fetch within my component?

Comment: you can try and use `axios`

Comment: It's still failing and I can't tell if the request is made or not

Comment: could you please copy the exact test you wrote and the response that you are getting

Comment: I don't have a test anymore, I generally don't know how to approach this. I want to test that when a `groupId` is provided to the component, useEffect will call getGroups and render the params in my src url for the iframe

Comment: if you meant to test just to make sure that the calls go out you can check network tab in chromes inspect area. If you mean to test as in unit test I need to see what you have written.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it didn't work. Im trying this now but that's not working either

Answer (score -3):

You can set a timeout to asynchronously check if the the expected condition has been met.

```
it('handles groupId and api call ', (done) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<UsageWidget surface={`${USAGE_SURFACES.metrics}`} groupId={1} />) 
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(wrapper.find("iframe").prop('src')).toBeTruthy(); // or whatever
    done();
  }, 5000);
}
```

The timeout lets you wait for the async fetch to complete. Call `done()` at the end to signal that the `it()` block is complete.

You probably also want to do a [mock implementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-implementations) of your `getGroups` function so that you're not actually hitting a network API every time you test your code.

Comment: Using a hardcoded timeout creates a race condition that generates false negatives at worst. At best, it slows down your test suite to take 5 seconds for a test that should be instantaneous. Use `new Promise(setImmediate)` and `wrapper.update()` to flush and detect the changes without a timeout as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59604256/6243352).