# How can I test a component style modified by a SetTimeout fired on useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, ts-jest

I'm using Jest/Enzyme to test a React/TypeScript application and I'm having a hard time trying to write a test to assert if a button shows up after a certain period of time:

Here's a very simplified version of the component to be tested:

```
import { StyledNotifyButton } from './styles'; //style-component element

const SomeComponent = (): ReactElement => {
  const [showNotifyButton, toggleNotifyButton] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => toggleNotifyButton(true), 5000);
  }, [toggleNotifyButton]);

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledNotifyButton visible={showNotifyButton} />
    </div>
  );
```

Here's the test:

```
 describe('< FailingTest >', () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;

  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<SomeComponent />);
  });

  it('should display the notify button only after X seconds', done => {
    let notifyButton = wrapper.find('StyledNotifyButton');

    jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation(f => f());
    expect(notifyButton.prop('visible')).toBe(false);

    jest.useFakeTimers();
    setTimeout(() => {
      wrapper.update();
      notifyButton = wrapper.find('NotifyButton');
      expect(notifyButton.prop('visible')).toBe(true);
      wrapper.unmount();
      done();
    }, 5000);
    jest.runAllTimers();
  });
```

I have already tries using fakeTimers, advanceTimersByTime, runAllTimers as explained in [Just Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks)

I've tried setTimeouts, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478730/jest-react-testing-check-state-after-delay)

Manually firing useEffect, as [here](https://blog.carbonfive.com/shallow-testing-hooks-with-enzyme/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147444/trigger-useeffect-in-jest-testing)

And many other ways... but I always get

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: true
Received: false
```

Any ideas on how to correctly get the visibility change after the timeout??
Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently struggling with unit testing myself: lots of side effetlcts, async logic, custom hooks (jest, enzyme, rosie factories). I'm trying everything from stack overflow answers and GitHub issues. I'm new to unit testing and the project code base is already vast. If you'd like to get in touch and share your experience and cases - I'm open to discussion via modern messengers and email.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the component is mounted, `useEffect` and `setTimeout` will be executed, you need to use [jest.useFakeTimers(implementation?: 'modern' | 'legacy')](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestusefaketimersimplementation-modern--legacy) before mounting the component.

Use [jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrunonlypendingtimers) to

> Executes only the macro-tasks that are currently pending (i.e., only the tasks that have been queued by setTimeout() or setInterval() up to this point)

Or [jest.advanceTimersByTime(msToRun)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestadvancetimersbytimemstorun).

Besides, we need to wrap the code rendering it and performing updates inside an [act()](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act) call, So put `jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()` in `act()`.

Finally, we need to call `wrapper.update()` to make sure the state reflect to the view.

E.g.

`SomeComponent.tsx`:

```
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyledNotifyButton } from './styles';

export const SomeComponent = (): ReactElement => {
  const [showNotifyButton, toggleNotifyButton] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      toggleNotifyButton(true);
    }, 5000);
  }, [toggleNotifyButton]);

  console.log('showNotifyButton: ', showNotifyButton);

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledNotifyButton visible={showNotifyButton} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`styles.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function StyledNotifyButton({ visible }) {
  return <button>click me</button>;
}
```

`SomeComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { SomeComponent } from './SomeComponent';

describe('67440874', () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;

  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    wrapper = mount(<SomeComponent />);
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    let notifyButton = wrapper.find('StyledNotifyButton');
    expect(notifyButton.prop('visible')).toBe(false);
    act(() => {
      jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    });
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find('StyledNotifyButton').prop('visible')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67440874/SomeComponent.test.tsx
  67440874
    ✓ should pass (8 ms)

  console.log
    showNotifyButton:  false

      at SomeComponent (examples/67440874/SomeComponent.tsx:13:11)

  console.log
    showNotifyButton:  true

      at SomeComponent (examples/67440874/SomeComponent.tsx:13:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.721 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
"jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
```

Comment: Thank you! It's hard to find some information about it...